# Different versions of MSBuild when installing directly or through visual studio

Tags: msbuild, roslyn

I've installed 'Microsoft Build Tools 2015' through the microsoft website. However, this installs a different MSBuild then what I get when I install Visual Studio. Specifically, the file "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll" is of version 1.0.0 when installing MSBuild directly, but has version 1.1.0 when installed through Visual Studio.

This difference is causing my project to only build locally, where I have Visual Studio installed, but not on my build server, which had MSBuild installed directly. The project is using a Roslyn diagnostic that references Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll 1.1.0.

Does anyone know why the MSBuild tool installer is using older Roslyn .dll's? When can I expect the MSBuild tools installer to be updated to the newest Roslyn version?

What are my options here? I can simply copy the local MSBuild folder that I got when installing VS to my buildserver, but it's a bit of an awkward process, especially when configuring multiple buildservers. Should I change my Roslyn diagnostic so it references 1.0.0, or can I package the 1.1.0 dll into the diagnostic's nuget package?

Comment: How are you referencing the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis DLLs? Are you referencing the direct assemblies under Program Files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 SP1 uses MSBuild 14.0 with some updates (14.0.24720.0), while what you download is MSBuild 14.0.23107.10,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild

https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases

That can explain the differences you observed.

Unless Microsoft provides a newer update of the individual MSBuild download, you are supposed to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on your build server.

Created an issue to inform MSBuild guys, https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/507 See how they respond.

Comment: This is direct link to the latest update tools as of now: [Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 2](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-build-tools).